# Datatables one th with two filters inside

Tags: datatables

I have a specific design issue, I have an `th`that have two filters, `firstname` and `surname` in the first `th`.

1 - How can I disable the default trigger inside the first `tr`, and add my trigger to firstname and surname?

2 - I added a hidden second `th` for the surname `td.hidden A1`, since it not should exist in the layout, but needs to be filtred

[image]

The first row always show both Firstname and Surname:
`td Mr Y A1`

```
.simple-table.highlight-header
    table.js-table-sort(data-table)
        thead
            tr
                th(data-title-first-surname)
                    .simple-table-toggle-legend(data-firstname-trigger) First name
                    .simple-table-toggles
                        .icon.icon-toggle-up
                        .icon.icon-toggle-down

                    .simple-table-toggle-legend(data-surname-trigger) Surname
                    .simple-table-toggles
                        .icon.icon-toggle-up
                        .icon.icon-toggle-down
                th.hidden Surname
        tbody
            tr
                td Mr Y A1
                td.hidden A1
            tr
                td Mr X A3
                td.hidden A3
            tr
                td Mr Max A2
                td.hidden A2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean exactly but I think [this](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/dqtbbpeh/) should do what you need:

```
var forenames=[],surnames=[];
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": [
        null, 
        {
            "render": function(data, type, row) {
                var names = data.split(" ");
                ~forenames.indexOf(names[0]) || forenames.push(names[0]);
                ~surnames.indexOf(names[1]) || surnames.push(names[1]);
                return data;
            },
            "sortable": false

        },
        null
    ],
    "initComplete": function() {
        var $forenames = $("#forename"),$surnames = $("#surname");
        forenames.forEach(function(x){
            $forenames.append($("<option></option>",{
                "value":x,
                "text":x
            }));
        });
        surnames.forEach(function(x){
            $surnames.append($("<option></option>",{
                "value":x,
                "text":x
            }));
        });
        $forenames.on("change", function(){
            table.columns(1).search($(this).val() + " " + $surnames.val()).draw();
        });
        $surnames.on("change", function(){
            table.columns(1).search($forenames.val() + " " + $(this).val()).draw();
        });        
    }
});
```

If we populate a  couple of arrays with unique forenames and surnames then we can create a couple of select boxes with the names and run a search on those upon the value changing. We can also set `sortable` to false to stop the table ordering on click of the header cell. Hope that helps.